# Challenge in configuring the CD website on developer’s machine

Tags: 2011

We are working on a Java based Tridion application which have Redhat Linux at content delivery server.
Now developers require configuring a local website that uses the Tridion API which will connect to the broker database so that they can write and debug the Tridion API code before integrating/deploying it through Tridion.
We all developers are working on window 7 based machines. As we all know that to configure this Tridion website locally at developers machine will need to install Tridion content delivery components which will have a licensing impact.
Due to certain policies,client is not allowing us to work on their Redhat Linux based content delivery development server.
What we should suggest to client to make developer’s job easy and faster.Below are the queries in my head.Could you guys suggest something on this –

> 1-Is it good to suggest client to share the CDA website directory with
>   each developer and open it in locally installed eclipse java IDE at
>   window 7 based machines?Is it possible to share this Redhat Linux based
>   website directory to window 7 user and run/debug the website through
>   eclipse?
>
> 2- Is it possible to acquire one/few CDA license with no cost from
>   Tridion for configuring website at developer’s local machine?
>
> 3-Is there any other way to configure website this locally in our
>   environment please suggest? Thanks

**UPDATE -** I am a bit more attracted with above option 1 as I had configured the similar asp.net website remotly in the visual studio earlier. But here i am a bit less confident becasue of below reasons -

(a) Here CD server have  Redhat Linux and where i was configured such website, both CD and developer's machine were windows based.

(b)- I am not sure that eclipse IDE also have such remotely configurable option similar to visual studio.

Do anybody have any such knowledge please share.

Comment: Also consider virtual machines, either locally or on (your or the client's) servers to help manage licenses, keep configuration centralized, or work across OS's.

Answer (score 3):

For any case having CD Website on your machine you need CD license. Check with your client/partner what kind of Contract they have with SDL for CD licenses. There are options of Temp licenses(3-4 months) also with SDL.

Comment: Thanks a lot Raj . Let me get in touch with SDL for temp license.

Answer (score 3):

1. I'm presuming you are working on a statically published websites (with
   a webroot full of JSP files) you'd like to share - if you run on
   DD4T (or CWA), this is simpler.

   What you do is setup a Samba (SMB) share on the redhat machine. This
   share can be attached to a windows machine as a network drive, which
   will allow your developers to mount this inside of Eclipse.

   From there on, i strongly suggest you develop a simple servlet
   filter for local development which grabs the jsp files on-the-fly
   from that share into your local eclipse development environment (a
   bit like the siteedit filter does), to have a clean seperation
   between published content and your development environment. From
   there on, everything runs on your localhost so you can debug as you
   please.
2. Ask SDL nicely for temporary development licences which are not bound to machine names
3. Copy-paste the JSP's you need by hand from the server using something like SSH / Cyberduck / your-fav-tool-here; or perhaps run on DD4T :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a war file, i.e. the codebase, that will be the shell of the application with all dependencies which can be deployed to any java app server. Then have the developers use that on individual machines.

What would you have done if this was an asp.net application? It's really no different for java.

Comment: Thanks Nickoli for your suggestion. Could you please give some insight and possibilty of option 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Speak to SDL Support about option 2, I'm sure if you're a partner and you need short term CD licencing for a select number of developers they can help you out

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Neil for answering.Could you please give some insight and possibilty about option 1 in my question ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm .NET myself - never touched Java!

Answer (score 2):

There's already multiple answers about the License, so I won't bother with that one.

When developing with Java - coming from a .NET background - you'll have to learn the ropes with Eclipse. The easiest way to get Tridion up & running within Eclipse, in my experience, is to import a pre-configured WAR file (see [this article](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/deployer-and-odata-3.aspx) in SDL Tridion World for an example - the article is specific for a deployer web app, but you would follow the same steps for a "standard" Tridion Web Application).

Once you have that configured, the rest is easy. Eclipse might seem unfriendly at first, but after a while you'll get used to it.